# Non weakly-group-theoretical integral fusion category

Tags: ct.category-theory, oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories

Is there an integral fusion category of rank $7$, FPdim $210$ and type $(1,5,5,5,6,7,7)$ with the following fusion rules (or the little $\color{purple}{\text{variation}}$ below)?

$$\scriptsize{\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \ 
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \ 
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \ 
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 2& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 2 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 2& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2& \color{purple}{1}& \color{purple}{2} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& \color{purple}{2}& \color{purple}{2} 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& \color{purple}{2}& \color{purple}{2} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2& \color{purple}{2}& \color{purple}{1} 
\end{smallmatrix}}$$

This is the *first known* non-trivial simple integral fusion ring. It was found by computation with SageMath ([this code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0eW8zTlRrWmFkX0U/view?usp=sharing) giving [this output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0eXlOMFQ5aktrVms/view?usp=sharing) after 2 minutes). Note that there is no finite simple group of order $210$, because the order of a (non-trivial) perfect group is divisible by $4$ (but see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211000/34538)).

Note that $210 = 2\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7$ and that the above matrices are irreducible; they are also self-dual and commuting, so simultaneously diagonalizable. We deduce the following "formal" character table:

$$\scriptsize \begin{array}{c|c}  
\text{class}&C_1&C_2&C_3&C_4&C_5&C_6&C_7 \newline  
\text{size}&1&35&30&30&30&42&42 \newline \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \newline 
\chi_2 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & 0 & 0 \newline 
\chi_3 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & 0 & 0  \newline 
\chi_4 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & 0 & 0  \newline 
\chi_5 & 6 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1  \newline 
\chi_6 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \zeta_5+\zeta_5^4 & \zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3  \newline 
\chi_7 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \zeta_5^2+\zeta_5^3 & \zeta_5+\zeta_5^4  \newline 
\end{array} $$

See [Schur orthogonality relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_orthogonality_relations) and [Orbit-Stabilizer theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Orbit-Stabilizer_Theorem) together with [MR2863455](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2863455).

Assume the existence of an integral fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ having the above fusion ring.

**Theorem**: The integral fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ would be not weakly-group-theoretical.
*Proof*: the fusion ring is simple, so the result follows by [MR2735754](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2735754) Proposition 9.11. because there is no simple group of order $210$.  $\square$

**Theorem**: The integral fusion category $\mathcal{C}$ would be abelian but not braided.
*Proof*: it is abelian because the above matrices commute. Now, if it's braided, then it can be non-degenerated (i.e. $\mathcal{C}′=Vec$) or degenerated:

- If it's non-degenerated then the contradiction follows by [MR3077244](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3077244) Corollary 6.16.
- Else it's degenerated, then $Vec \subsetneq \mathcal{C}′$, so by simplicity $\mathcal{C}′=\mathcal{C}$, so $\mathcal{C}$ is symmetric, and by Deligne (see [MR3077244](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3077244) Example 4.6 citing [MR1106898](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1106898)), $\mathcal{C}≃Rep(G)$ as fusion category (without considering the symmetric structure), with $G$ a finite simple group, contradiction. $\square$

*Remark*: A pointed fusion category is equivalent to $Vec_{G, \omega}$ with $G$ a finite group and $\omega$ a $3$-cocycle in $Z^3 (G, \mathbb{C}^*)$ as associator. In particular, the fusion ring of a pointed fusion category is trivial.

**Aknowledgment**: The above theorems were discussed during the [workshop on fusion categories](http://schauenburg.perso.math.cnrs.fr/announcement.html) (May 2013, IMB Dijon, France). Thanks to Peter Schauenburg for his invitation, and thanks to Eric Rowell, Leonid Vainermann and David Penneys for above references and encouragements.

---

There is a second integral simple fusion ring of same FPdim, type and rules except  a little $\color{purple}{\text{variation}}$ for the $7$-dimensional simple objects (and multiplicity $3$ instead of $2$):

$$\scriptsize{\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 0& 0& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 1& 0& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 1& 0& 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0& 1& 1& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 2& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 2 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 1& 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 2& 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2& {\color{purple}{0}}& {\color{purple}{3}} \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& {\color{purple}{3}}& {\color{purple}{1}} 
\end{smallmatrix} , \
\begin{smallmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0& 0& 0& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& 1& 2 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1& 1& {\color{purple}{3}}& {\color{purple}{1}} \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1& 2& {\color{purple}{1}}& {\color{purple}{2}} 
\end{smallmatrix}}$$

All the properties above hold for this fusion ring. Here is the corresponding formal character table:

$$\scriptsize \begin{array}{c|c}  
\text{class}&C_1&C_2&C_3&C_4&C_5&C_6&C_7 \newline  
\text{size}&1&35&30&30&30&70&14 \newline \hline
\chi_1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \newline 
\chi_2 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & 0 & 0 \newline 
\chi_3 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & 0 & 0  \newline 
\chi_4 & 5 & -1 & -\zeta_7^4 - \zeta_7^3 & -\zeta_7 -\zeta_7^6 & -\zeta_7^5 - \zeta_7^2 & 0 & 0  \newline 
\chi_5 & 6 & 0 & -1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & 1  \newline 
\chi_6 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -3  \newline 
\chi_7 & 7 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 2  \newline 
\end{array}  $$

---

*About the original motivation*
These matrices came from my will of classifying the cyclic subfactors (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/133050/34538) and [MR3708264](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3708264)). I first wondered whether there is an irreducible finite index depth $2$ maximal subfactor which is not a group subfactor, in other words, a finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra (or Kac algebra) nontrivial and without left coideal $\star$-subalgebra (see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/211000/34538)). Such a Kac algebra must be simple.
Now a Kac algebra gives a unitary integral fusion category. [This algorithm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0eW8zTlRrWmFkX0U/view?usp=sharing) investigates all the (non-trivial) simple integral fusion rings. There are finitely many possibilities for each dimension.

*Other examples* $\DeclareMathOperator\PSL{PSL} \DeclareMathOperator\Rep{Rep}$
See the [Atlas of Fusion Rings](https://sites.google.com/view/sebastienpalcoux/fusion-rings), providing thousands of new simple integral fusion rings, by improved brute-force classification, interpolation and isotypical variations. The interpolation is very promising, it should provide infinite families, see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/367990/34538) dedicated to this method: there we show that the first fusion ring above would be the Grothendieck ring of an interpolation called $“\Rep(\PSL(2,6))”$, whereas the second above is just a specific isotypical variation of the first.

Comment: I am interested to know how you got those matrices: where do they come from?

Comment: Kac algebras are not completely given by a unitary fusion category. You can have two non isomorphic Kac algebras with the same tensor category of representation, for example, a Drinfeld twist deformation of a group algebra.

Comment: Yes, twist deformations of finite dimensional Hopf algebras have the same category of representation, look for example http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0107167.pdf A finite dimensional Hopf algebra is completely determined by their category of representation and its fiber functor.

Comment: In the same flavor that Cérar's comment, see the paper of Etingof-Gelaki : [Isocategorical Groups](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007196.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

*Partial answer*

The second fusion ring admits no *unitary* categorification. It is proved in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12059v1), using Character Table and Fourier Analysis. Here are some explanations:

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a commutative fusion ring. Then its fusion matrices $(M_i)$ are commuting and normal so simultaneously diagonalisable: there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}M_iP = diag(\lambda_{i,j})$. Let us call $\Lambda=(\lambda_{i,j})$ the *character table* of $\mathcal{F}$. Note that if $G$ is a finite group and $\mathcal{F}$ the Grothendieck ring of $Rep(G)$ then $\Lambda$ is the usual character table of $G$.

If $\mathcal{F}$ is the Grothendieck ring of a unitary fusion category, and if we choose $\lambda_{i,1}$ to be $\Vert M_i \Vert$, then by Corollary 7.5 in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.12059v1), for every triple $(j,k,\ell)$ $$\sum_i \frac{\lambda_{i,j}\lambda_{i,k}\lambda_{i,\ell}}{\lambda_{i,1}} \ge 0.$$
Note that for $Rep(G)$ this identity admits a combinatorial/probabilistic interpretation (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/344968/34538)).

Now observe the character table of the second fusion ring above, in particular its last column, then
$$ \frac{1^3}{1} + \frac{0^3}{5} + \frac{0^3}{5} + \frac{0^3}{5} + \frac{1^3}{6} + \frac{(-3)^3}{7} + \frac{2^3}{7} =  -\frac{65}{42}<0.$$
It follows that the second fusion ring above admits no unitary categorification.

Note that the identity holds for the first fusion ring.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still new to this specific field, so I apologize in advance if I have this wrong.

EDIT:  <strike>Neither example is categorifiable.</strike> [The answer is still unkown to me.]

If you let $M_i$ be the fusion matrices for $i=1...7$ and $A = \sum_{i=1}^7 M_i M_{i^*}$.  Then the eigenvalues of $A$ are the formal codegrees [arxiv:0810.3242v2](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.3242v2.pdf).   <strike>However, both of your cases yield a matrix $A$ with three eigenvalues equal to 0.</strike>  [I did not compute your $A$ matrix correctly.]

Comment: Ryan, I don't think this is correct. Certainly Cor 1.7 of Victor's paper doesn't say that codegrees are non-zero (zero is a rational integer...). Moreover, there are counterexamples to this claim. The first one I came up with is $SU(3)_4$, discussed for example in http://arxiv.org/abs/1205.2742.

Comment: @Scott, I don't think the formal codegrees can be zero. For example, see Section 2.3 of arXiv:1309.4822. However, if A is the matrix in the answer above, then it's a positive definite operator which is $\geq I$, the identity, since $M_1=I$. Thus all it's eigenvalues are at least 1, regardless of whether they are fusion matrices or not. So there must be an error somewhere...

Comment: Yup, there's definitely an error in my computations (which were in the FusionAtlas mathematica package...). I was assuming that dimension functions were real, and computing $\sum d_i^2$ instead of $\sum |d_i|^2$.

Comment: @DavePenneys: you're right because $M_{i^*}= M_i^* (= M_i)$.

Comment: I've computed the Jordan form of $A$ and I've obtained $diag(210, 6, 5, 5, 7, 7, 7)$ for the first fusion ring and $diag(210, 15, 6, 3, 7, 7, 7)$ for the second. I don't know how interpreting all these numbers and their multiplicities.

Comment: In the group case, these numbers would be the order of the centralizers for a representative of each conjugacy class (and so the *indices* of the conjugacy classes by the Orbit-Stabilizer Theorem, which should justify the name *formal codegree*). I edited the *formal character table*.