# Normal intermediate subgroup and normal core

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, subfactors

Let $G$ be a finite group and $H$ a subgroup.

The **normal core** of $H$ in $G$ is  $core_G(H) := \bigcap_{g \in G}g^{-1}Hg$

**Definition**: $K$ is a **normal intermediate subgroup** of the inclusion $(H \subset G)$  if   $H \subset K \subset G$,    and  $$\forall g \in G \text{ , } KgH=HgK$$ (This definition is motivated by the prop.3.3 p476 of [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/journal-of-the-mathematical-society-of-japan/volume-50/issue-2/Normal-intermediate-subfactors/10.2969/jmsj/05020469.full))

**Examples** : If $H=\{ e \}$ then $K$ is a normal intermediate subgroup iff $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.
$H_i$ and $G_i$ are obviously normal intermediate subgroups of the inclusion $(H_i \subset G_i)$, and
$H_1 \times G_2$ and $G_1 \times H_2$ are normal intermediate subgroups of $(H_1 \times H_2 \subset G_1 \times G_2)$.

Let $L$ and $K$ be normal intermediate subgroups of  $(H \subset G)$,  then $\langle K , L \rangle = KL=LK$.

> **Question** : Is it true that $\forall k \in K$,   $k.core_{KL}(K) \cap L \neq \emptyset$ ?

**Remark**: it's true for all the examples above: it's obvious if  $H=\{ e \}$ , or if $\{ K , L  \} \subset \{ H, G   \} $,
and if $G = G_1 \times G_2$, $H = H_1 \times H_2$, $K=H_1 \times G_2$ and $L = G_1 \times H_2$, then $KL=G$ and   $\{ e \}  \times G_2 \subset core_{KL}(K)$, so if $k \in K$, $k=(h_1,g_2)$ and $(h_1,g_2).(e,g_2^{-1}) = (h_1,e) \in L$.

---

**Motivation**: This question is (for me) the last step for getting a **Jordan-Hölder** theorem generalized to the inclusions of groups, as explained [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156311/jordan-h%C3%B6lder-theorem-for-subfactors/158685#158685) in the context of group-subgroup subfactors.

**Definition**: An inclusion $(H \subset G)$ is **simple** if it admits no non-trivial normal intermediate subgroup.

**Examples**:  The maximal inclusions are obviously simple, and if $H=\{ e \}$,  it's simple iff $G$ is simple.
$(\mathbb{Z}_3 \subset A_5)$  is an example of simple inclusion which is neither maximal nor trivial.

Comment: See the augmented post: [A second isomorphism theorem for the inclusions of groups](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159167/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-the-inclusions-of-groups)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, $(D_{10} \subset A_6)$ gives a counterexample.

It has exactly two non-trivial intermediate subgroups $K$ and $L$, each isomorphic to $A_5$ (see [here](http://homepages.ulb.ac.be/~tconnor/atlaslat/alt6.pdf)) and  normal intermediate subgroups, thanks to a SAGE-GAP computation (see [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_alternating_group:A6) for the generators):

```
sage: G=AlternatingGroup(6)
sage: H=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),G("(2,5)(3,4)")])
sage: K=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3)])
sage: L=G.subgroup([(1,2,3,4,5),G("(1,4) (5,6)")])
sage: P1=[Set([G(i)*k*G(j) for i in H for j in K]) for k in G]
sage: P2=[Set([G(j)*k*G(i) for i in H for j in K]) for k in G]
sage: P3=[Set([G(i)*k*G(j) for i in H for j in L]) for k in G]
sage: P4=[Set([G(j)*k*G(i) for i in H for j in L]) for k in G]
sage: P1==P2
True
sage: P3==P4
True
```

$KL=A_6$ is simple, so $core_{KL}(K) = \{ e \}$, but $K \not\subset L$.
Then $\exists k \in K$ such that $k.core_{KL}(K) \cap L = \emptyset.$

**Remark**: Nevertheless, the inclusion $(D_{10} \subset A_6)$ checks Jordan-Hölder (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/156311/jordan-holder-theorem-for-subfactors/159112#159112)).

Comment: See the augmented post: [A second isomorphism theorem for the inclusions of groups](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/159167/a-second-isomorphism-theorem-for-the-inclusions-of-groups)