# Double coset relation for unique intermediate subgroup (with homogeneity)

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, permutation-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subgroup such that there is a **unique** (non-trivial) intermediate subgroup $K$  (i.e. $H < S < G$ implies $S=K$) **and**   $(H \subset K) \sim (K \subset G)$ (**homogeneity**)

Recall that $(H \subset K) \sim (K \subset G)$ if $(H/H_K \subset K/H_K) \simeq (K/K_G \subset G/K_G)$,  with $H_K$ the [normal core](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Normal_core) (in others words, these inclusions define the same transitive permutation group).

**Remark**:  $G$ **can't** be a finite simple group. In fact $K/H_K \simeq G/K_G$ so **if** $G$ is a finite simple group, then  $K_G=\{ e \}$, and so $\vert G \vert \le \vert K \vert$, **contradiction**.

**Examples**:  Up to $\sim$,  there are exactly $123$  such inclusions of groups  of index $\le 30$.
The first examples are $(\{e\} \subset \mathbb{Z}_{p^2})$ 
and  $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \subset D_{p^2} )$.

> **Question**: Is it true that $HgK=KgH$, $\forall g \in G$ ?

**Experiment** (GAP):   It's checked for $\vert G \vert \le 2000$, except $1024$ and $1536$.
It's also true if $[G:H] \le 30$  (see [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/720542/a-relation-for-the-inclusions-of-groups-with-a-unique-intermediate/721164#comment1507674_721164) of Derek Holt).

Comment: This question is a very particular case of [Are the homogeneous single chain subfactors, Dedekind?](http://mathoverflow.net/q/160577/34538)