# Generalization of the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, lattice-theory, computational-group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group then the [fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups) can be formulated as follows:
*Theorem*: $G$ is cyclic iff it admits no two different subgroups with the same order.
*proof*: see [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eWkqG0aiVsMC&lpg=PP1&dq=.%20Fundamentals%20of%20Group%20Theory:%20An%20Advanced%20Approach&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) p44 together with [Lagrange theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)). $\square$

But there is an other characterization of the finite cyclic groups, using the lattice theory:
*Theorem*: $G$ is cyclic iff its subgroups lattice $\mathcal{L}(G)$ is [distributive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice).
*proof*: see [here](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/duke-mathematical-journal/volume-4/issue-2/Structures-and-group-theory-II/10.1215/S0012-7094-38-00419-3.short) theorem 4 p267.  $\square$

So we get immediately the following statement for a finite group $G$:
If $G$ admits no two different subgroups with the same order, then its subgroups lattice is distributive.

We ask about a generalization of this statement for an inclusion $(H \subset G)$ of finite groups:

**Question**: Is it true that if $(H \subset G)$ admits no two different intermediate subgroups $H \subset K \subset G$ with the same order, then its intermediate subgroups lattice $\mathcal{L}(H \subset G)$ is distributive?

*Remark*: It is checked (by GAP) for $[G:H] \le 31$.
The converse is false because the inclusion $(S_2 \times S_2 \subset S_3 \times S_3)$ is a counter-example (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/157860/34538)).

Comment: What does "at most one subgroup of fixed order" mean? It is not true that if a group G has only one subgroup of some given order, then G must be cyclic. Perhaps what is wanted is that there are no two different subgroups with the same order.

Comment: @MartyIsaacs: you're right, your last sentence is what I had in mind. I've edited that.

Comment: See the sequel: [Generalization of the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups 2](http://mathoverflow.net/q/206188/34538)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say $G=S_n$ and $H$ is a Young subgroup with three orbits, no two of which have the same size and no two of which have sizes summing to $n/2$.  Then the only subgroups between $H$ and $G$ should be three Young subgroups with two orbits, no one of which contains any other and no two of which have the same order.

Comment: I've checked the smallest example $(S_1 \times S_2 \times S_4 \subset S_7)$ of index $105$, and it runs as you state. To prove your statement in general you use the result that $(S_n \times S_m \subset S_{n+m})$ is a maximal inclusion (I believe it's proved somewhere on MO).