# Generalization of the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups 2

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups, computational-group-theory

This post is a sequel of [Generalization of the fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/205977/generalization-of-the-fundamental-theorem-of-cyclic-groups)

Let $G$ be a finite group then the [fundamental theorem of cyclic groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups) can be formulated as follows:
*Theorem*: $G$ is cyclic iff it admits no two different subgroups with the same order.
*proof*: see [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=eWkqG0aiVsMC&lpg=PP1&dq=.%20Fundamentals%20of%20Group%20Theory%3A%20An%20Advanced%20Approach&hl=fr&pg=PP1#v=onepage&q&f=false) p44 together with [Lagrange theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29). $\square$

We ask about a generalization of one side of this statement for an inclusion $(H \subset G)$ of finite groups:

*Definition*: $G$ is called $H$-cyclic if $\exists g \in G$ such that $\langle H,g \rangle = G$.

**Question**: Is it true that if $(H \subset G)$ admits no two different intermediate subgroups $H \subset K \subset G$ with the same order, then $G$ is $H$-cyclic?

*Remark*: It is checked (by GAP) for $[G:H] \le 31$ and [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/205979/34538) of John Shareshian gives examples beyond.  The converse is false because the inclusion $(S_2 \times S_2 \subset S_3 \times S_3)$ is a counter-example.