# Weakly group theoretical fusion category and subsystems

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, fusion-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a fusion category and $H$ a semi-simple finite weak Hopf algebra such that $\mathcal{C}(H) = \mathcal{C}$.
Suppose that for every nontrivial left coideal subalgebras $S$ of $H$ or $H^{*}$, then   $\mathcal{C}(S)$ weakly group theoretical.
Suppose also that $H$ admits a nontrivial left coideal subalgebra.

*Question*: Can we deduce that $\mathcal{C}$ is also weakly group theoretical?

*Remark*: this question should be weaker than the famous question:
Is a fusion category  weakly integral iff it's weakly group theoretical?