# Is an integral simple fusion ring, categorifiable?

Tags: ct.category-theory, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, subfactors, fusion-categories

A **fusion ring** $\mathcal{F}$ (see [here](http://www.imsc.res.in/~sunder/pf.pdf) p 28) is **integral** if the Perron-Frobenius dimension $d(h_i)$ of its basic elements $\{h_1,...,h_r\}$, are integers.   Its **rank** is $r$ and its **dimension** is $\sum d(h_i)^2$.
   $\mathcal{F}$ is **simple** if it has no non-trivial fusion subring.

$\mathcal{F}$ is **categorifiable** if it is the Grothendieck ring of a fusion category (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0203060)).
(The pentagonal equation has a solution)

Let $Rep(G)$ be the fusion category of representations of a finite group $G$.
The Grothendieck ring $\mathcal{F}(G)$ of $Rep(G)$, is simple iff $G$ is a simple group.

Every integral simple fusion ring of rank $<9$ and dimension $<210$,  are **trivial** (i.e. $\simeq \mathcal{F}(G)$), and so are categorifiable.

> **Question** : Is an integral simple fusion ring, always categorifiable ?

The first non-trivial simple integral fusion ring I know, is rank $7$ and dimension $210$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132866/non-weakly-group-theoretical-integral-fusion-categories)).

Comment: I am not an expert on this topic but in Dave Penneys' answer to [this other thread](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/214934/classification-of-finite-abelian-hypergroups-and-table-algebras) it is mentioned that it is not known whether rank 4 fusion rings are categorifiable.

Comment: [Here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/344806/34538) is a simple integral fusion ring ruled out from unitary categorification. [This atlas](https://sites.google.com/view/sebastienpalcoux/fusion-rings) provides many simple integral fusion rings without any categorification. So the answer is **no**.