# Is there a non-trivial Hopf algebra without left coideal subalgebra?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, hopf-algebras, subfactors, fusion-categories

Let $H$ be a finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra.
A $\star$-subalgebra $I$ of $H$ is a *left coideal* if $\Delta(I) \subset H \otimes I$.
$H$ is called *maximal* if it has no left coideal $\star$-subalgebra other than $\mathbb{C}$ and $H$.

**Question**: Is there a non-trivial maximal finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra?
(*non-trivial* means not the Hopf algebra of a group)

*Remark*: The Hopf algebra of a group is maximal iff the group is cyclic of prime order. There is [this paper](http://imrn.oxfordjournals.org/content/1994/1/53.full.pdf) of Y. Zhu proving that the Hopf algebras of prime dimension are group algebras, so this result answers my question for the prime dimension case, but not in general.

See [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132866/34538) for the Grothendieck ring of what *could be* the first maximal non-trivial Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra.

---

*Motivation*: A finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^{\star}$-algebra $H$ (also called Kac algebra) acts outerly on the hyperfinite ${\rm II}_1$ [factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_algebra#Factors) $R$. We can build the [subfactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subfactor) $(R \subset R \rtimes H)$, remembering $H$, and whose isomorphism class is independent of the choice of the action. But there is a $1$-$1$ [Galois correspondence](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123697932286) between the set of intermediate subfactors of $(R \subset R \rtimes H)$, and the set of left coideal $\star$-subalgebras of $H$. Now  a subfactor $(A \subset B)$ without intermediate subfactor other than $A$ and $B$, is called *maximal*, moreover, the irreducible depth $2$ finite index subfactors are exactly the subfactors given by the Kac algebras. So the *motivation* here is to find a non-trivial maximal irreducible depth $2$ finite index subfactor.

Comment: I'm not sure how useful your definition of "quantum group" is or why the specific field $\mathbb{C}$ is required, but the parenthetic remark involving "if appropriate" and "finite dimensional" seems to add confusion.  Clarify (or perhaps just omit) this remark?

Comment: @JimHumphreys: What definition of quantum group do you suggest? Do you suggest a definition as general as possible, as "Hopf algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$", or do you suggest to just put the specific area I need for my own research (i.e. finite dimensional Hopf ${\rm C}^*$-algebra). I think this question is very natural and interesting in general, but if I get an answer outside of the area of my need, I should post an other question,  more specialized. I've edited the post, what do you think? Do you have an example for a field different of $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Maybe it's simpler to avoid the term "quantum group" here rather than attempt a precise definition.   I think Drinfeld was reluctant to give a general definition in the mid-1980s, since different notions arise in different subject areas.

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Ok, I've took off the term "quantum group".

Comment: @JimHumphreys: Is "minimal" the good word for this notion? Perhaps "prime" or rather "coprime" is better. Do you know some works about this problem, or a paper in which it is mentioned?

Comment: I must take $\mathbb{K}$ algebraically closed of characteristic $0$ (or $\mathbb{C}$), because of the last sentence of the first paragraph p15 [here](http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~sommerh/Publikationen/KaplConjwww/KaplConjPrep4Vers.ps). I could alternatively  replace "trivial" by "commutative and cocommutative".