# Is there an integral simple fusion ring rank<6, FPdim>60 and Frobenius type?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, qa.quantum-algebra, subfactors, fusion-categories, sage

A *fusion ring* is a finite dimensional $\mathbb{Z}$-module
$\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{B}$ together with a distinguished basis
$\mathcal{B} = \{ h_1,...,h_r\}$ and fusion rules $ h_i \cdot h_j =
 \sum_k n_{ij}^kh_k $, with $n_{ij}^k \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 0}$
satisfying:

- *Neutral*: $n_{1i}^j = n_{i1}^j = \delta_{ij}$
- *Dual*: there is an involution $i \mapsto i^*$ such that $n_{i^*j}^1=\delta_{i,j}$
- *Frobenius-Perron reciprocity*: $n_{ij}^k = n_{i^*k}^j = n_{kj^*}^i$,
- *Associativity*: $\sum_s n_{ij}^sn_{sk}^t = \sum_s n_{jk}^sn_{is}^t$

*Remark*: $\mathbb{C}\mathcal{B}$ admits a structure of finite dimensional ${\rm C}^*$-algebra (take $h_i^* = h_{i^*}$).
*Frobenius-Perron theorem*: $\exists!$ $*$-homomorphism $d:\mathbb{C}\mathcal{B} \to \mathbb{C}$ with $d(\mathcal{B}) \subset
 (0,\infty)$.

The *rank* $r$ of the fusion ring $\mathbb{C}\mathcal{B}$ is the cardinal of $\mathcal{B}$.
It is is called *integral* if every
$d(h_i)$ is an integer.
Its *Frobenius-Perron dimension* (FPdim) is $\sum d(h_i)^2$.
It is of *Frobenius type* if $\frac{FPdim(\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{B})}{d(h_i)}$ is an algebraic integer.
It is *simple* if $r>1$ and for any fusion subring $\mathbb{Z}\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}\mathcal{B}$ with $\mathcal{S} \subseteq \mathcal{B}$, then $\mathcal{S} = \{ h_1 \}$ or $\mathcal{B}$.

*Open problem*: Every Grothendieck ring of a complex fusion category is of Frobenius type.

*Remark*: The Grothendieck ring of a finite group $Rep(G)$ is the ring generated by the irreducible complex representations of $G$ (up to equiv.) for $\oplus$ and $\otimes$. It is a fusion ring, and it is simple iff $G$ is simple. So the notion of simple fusion ring generalizes the notion of simple group; it does **not** correspond to the usual notion of simple ring.

The fusion ring $\mathcal{G}_p$ is the fusion ring based on the cyclic group of prime order $p$.

We checked by SAGE (by using [this code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2P_JgZe-Zd0eW8zTlRrWmFkX0U/view?usp=sharing)) that the only integral simple fusion ring of Frobenius type, rank $\leq 5$ and FPdim $< 1000000$ (except $\mathcal{G}_p$) is the Grothendieck ring of the simple group $A_5$. It is of rank $5$ and FPdim $60$.

**Question**: Is there an integral simple fusion ring of rank $ \leq 5$,  FPdim $>60$ and Frobenius type?

---

*Bonus for rank $6$:*

We have checked by SAGE that the only integral simple fusion ring of Frobenius type, rank $6$ and FPdim $< 150000$ is the Grothendieck ring of the simple group ${\rm PSL}(2,7)$, of order $168$.

*Bonus question*: Is there an integral simple fusion ring of rank $6$,  FPdim $>168$ and Frobenius type?

---

A fusion ring is called non-group-like if it is not the Grothendieck ring of $Rep(G)$ or $Vec(G)$ with $G$ a finite group. The first non-group-like integral simple fusion ring found by SAGE is of rank $7$ and FPdim $210$ (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132866/34538)).

For $210 <$ FPdim $<15000$ and rank $7$, there are six integral simple fusion rings, two of FPdim $360$, one of which is the Grothendieck ring of the simple group $A_6$, the other is non-trivial, and four of FPdim $7980$ and type $[[1, 1], [19, 1], [20, 1], [21, 1], [42, 2], [57, 1]]$. See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.12059.pdf).