# Are the integer index finite depth irreducible subfactors Kac-coideal?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, hopf-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors, planar-algebras

Is every integer index finite depth irreducible subfactors planar algebra, the intermediate of an irreducible finite index depth $2$ subfactors planar algebra?
In other words, of the following form (called Kac-coideal):  $(R^{\mathbb{J}} \subset R^{\mathbb{I}})$ with $\mathbb{A}$ a finite dimensional Kac algebra and $\mathbb{I} \subset \mathbb{J} \subset \mathbb{A}$ left coideal subalgebras.

*Remark*: it seems relevant because without the integer index assumption, they are weak-Kac-coideal (see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0006057v2)  prop. 9.1.1 p 37) :   an irreducible depth $d$ finite index irreducible subfactor $(N \subset M)$ is an intermediate of the depth $2$ (non nec. irreducible) subfactor $(N \subset M_{d-2})$ which is (planar algebra) equivalent to $  (R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R)$, with $\mathbb{A}$ a finite dim. **weak** Kac algebra, so that $(N \subset M)$ is  (planar algebra) equivalent to $(R^{\mathbb{A}} \subset R^{\mathbb{I}})$ with $\mathbb{I}$ a left coideal subalgebra   of $\mathbb{A}$, thanks to the [Galois correspondence](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0001020).

*Remark*: without the "finite depth" assumption, it's false because you can take a $A_{\infty} * A_{\infty}$ subfactor planar algebra whose first component is non-integer index $\alpha > 4$ and the second $n/\alpha$ with an integer $n > 4 \alpha$, so that the whole subfactor is index $n$, but can't be Kac-coideal (because the indices of the intermediate subfactors of a Kac-coideal subfactor are integer).  Moreover, I don't know whether or not every $A_n$ or $A_{\infty}$ subfactor planar algebra *of integer index* are Kac-coideal.

Comment: The (maximal) subfactor of index $4$ and (dual) principal group $E_8^{(1)}$ is **not** a group-subgroup subfactor (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/384298/34538)). Is there a Kac-coideal model? Idem index $4$, for all $n \ge 4$, the principal graphs $D_n^{(1)}$ admits $n-2$ subfactor planar algebras, but there are just $5$ transitive permutation group of degree $4$, so infinitely many of these subfactors are not group-subgroup. Are they always Kac-coideal?